# Loop through multiple tags in Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop through multiple tags in the HTML so I can print all the IDs.
My code right now prints only first ID, how can I print the second, third, fourth and so on values.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

product_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'valu '})
product_tag = product_div[0].find('a')
products = product_tag.attrs['val']
print products
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the html your are parsing? Specifically what does `<div class=“size”>` actually look like and can it contain more than 1 `<a>` tag?

Comment: Hint: `find_all()` returns a list. How do you iterate on a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for product_div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'size '}):
    product_tag = product_div.find('a')
    if product_tag:
        print product_tag.attrs['id']
```